# PS 4.0 Parameters with Space - Catch Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm executing script in batch and passing 5 parameters separated by a comma via Java.  PS 4.0 accepts parameters without the "".

```
[CmdletBinding()]  
Param (
  [Parameter(Position = 0)]
  [string[]] $inpParms = $(throw 'Failure : This is required.')
)
```

I invoke the script like

```
myScript.ps1 user,pwd,Server Name, DLName,Action
```

It errors out due to the space in "Server Name". Throws error which spits back the parameters:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\myScript.ps1 user,pwd,Server Name, DLName,Create
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ExchangeDL.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,ExchangeDL.ps1
```

Is there a way to trap this error so I don't spit sensitive info in logs?

Answer (score 2):

While you don't have to quote arguments that don't have shell metacharacters in them, a space *is* a metacharacter, so you have two choices:

`` ` ``-quote the metacharacters *individually*:

```
./myScript.ps1 user, pwd, Server` Name, DLName, Create
```

Or use `"..."` (interpolating) or `'...'` (literal) to enclose entire arguments as needed:

```
./myScript.ps1 user, pwd, 'Server Name', DLName, Create
```

---

Generally, though, your script will be more maintainable if you define *individual* parameters rather than a single *array*.

---

If you want to *catch an incorrect invocation attempt*, use a `Try / Catch` statement:

```
Try {
  ./myScript.ps1 user, pwd, Server Name, DLName, Action
} Catch {
  Throw "Invocation of ./myScript.ps1 failed."
}
```

By not using the information from the statement-terminating error that the incorrect invocation produced (accessible as `$_` in the `Catch` block) in the `Throw` statement, the original command line is not leaked.